# setting QuickCharts color

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, pie-chart

I wanted to generate a pie-chart to include in an email body by generating < img src = "...." > tag. For that, i came across a chart library called Quickcharts(https://quickchart.io/) which is an open-source charting library.

Somehow, I don't know how to change the background color of each slice in Quickcharts. Currently, I have something like this,

[https://quickchart.io/chart?width=270&height=200&c={type:%27pie%27,data:{labels:[%27High%27,%27Medium%27,%20%27Low%27],%20datasets:[{data:[50,60,70]}]}}](https://quickchart.io/chart?width=270&height=200&c=%7Btype:%27pie%27,data:%7Blabels:%5B%27High%27,%27Medium%27,%20%27Low%27%5D,%20datasets:%5B%7Bdata:%5B50,60,70%5D%7D%5D%7D%7D)

I want to change the background color of pie chart and bring the quickcharts, something similar to this.

https://image-charts.com/chart?cht=pc&chco=4e73df%2C0f3dc4%2C9fb4f3&chd=t:11,110,69&chs=500x160&chl=5.8%25%7C57.9%25%7C36.3%25&chdl=High%7CMedium%7CLow

Let me know if anyone could help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Chart.js, you can set the background color of a pie chart with the `backgroundColor` attribute:

```js
{
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ['High', 'Medium', 'Low'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [50, 60, 70],
      backgroundColor: ['#4e73df', '#0f3dc4', '#9fb4f3']
    }]
  }
}
```

Additionally, you may want to change the color of the labels using the `datalabels` plugin:

```js
{
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ['High', 'Medium', 'Low'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [50, 60, 70],
      backgroundColor: ['#4e73df', '#0f3dc4', '#9fb4f3']
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        color: '#fff'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Pack it into the chart URL:

https://quickchart.io/chart?bkg=white&c=%7Btype%3A%27pie%27%2Cdata%3A%7Blabels%3A%5B%27High%27%2C%27Medium%27%2C%27Low%27%5D%2Cdatasets%3A%5B%7Bdata%3A%5B50%2C60%2C70%5D%2CbackgroundColor%3A%5B%27%234e73df%27%2C%27%230f3dc4%27%2C%27%239fb4f3%27%5D%7D%5D%7D%2Coptions%3A%7Bplugins%3A%7Bdatalabels%3A%7Bcolor%3A%27%23fff%27%7D%7D%7D%7D

And it will look like this:

[image: quickchart pie chart]

Comment: Hi there is just one more doubt that I have. Is it possible to scale the pie-chart to the size mentioned in the above image-charts link. I am able to use width=270&height=200 property, but as the size of the pie chart decreases, the distance between the legend and pie increases. If it is possible to display the legend vertically on the side of the pie chart, it would be great as well. Kindly let me know if you can help with this.

Comment: https://quickchart.io/chart?width=270&height=200&bkg=white&c=%7Btype%3A%27pie%27%2Cdata%3A%7Blabels%3A%5B%27High%27%2C%27Medium%27%2C%27Low%27%5D%2Cdatasets%3A%5B%7Bdata%3A%5B11%2C110%2C60%5D%2CbackgroundColor%3A%5B%27%234e73df%27%2C%27%230f3dc4%27%2C%27%239fb4f3%27%5D%7D%5D%7D%2Coptions%3A%7Bplugins%3A%7Bdatalabels%3A%7Bcolor%3A%27%23fff%27%7D%7D%7D%7D

Comment: Use Chart.js config for legend, position: 'right', align: 'top'.  Documentation here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration. Chart: https://quickchart.io/chart?width=270&height=200&bkg=white&c=%7Btype%3A%27pie%27%2Cdata%3A%7Blabels%3A%5B%27High%27%2C%27Medium%27%2C%27Low%27%5D%2Cdatasets%3A%5B%7Bdata%3A%5B11%2C110%2C60%5D%2CbackgroundColor%3A%5B%27%234e73df%27%2C%27%230f3dc4%27%2C%27%239fb4f3%27%5D%7D%5D%7D%2Coptions%3A%7Blegend%3A%7Bposition%3A%27right%27%2Calign%3A%27start%27%7D%2Cplugins%3A%7Bdatalabels%3A%7Bcolor%3A%27%23fff%27%7D%7D%7D%7D

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot, Sorry I am asking too much. It worked as intended. I changed the pie into doughnut now. Is there anyway to display text in the center of the doughnut?

Comment: https://quickchart.io/chart?width=270&height=100&bkg=white&c=%7Btype%3A%27doughnut%27%2Cdata%3A%7Blabels%3A%5B%27High%27%2C%27Medium%27%2C%27Low%27%5D%2Cdatasets%3A%5B%7Bdata%3A%5B11%2C110%2C60%5D%2CbackgroundColor%3A%5B%27%234e73df%27%2C%27%230f3dc4%27%2C%27%239fb4f3%27%5D%7D%5D%7D%2Coptions%3A%7Blegend%3A%7Bposition%3A%27right%27%2Calign%3A%27start%27%7D%2Cplugins%3A%7Bdatalabels%3A%7Bcolor%3A%27%23fff%27%7D%7D%7D%7D

Comment: Yup, use the `doughnutlabel` plugin.  Here's an example: https://gist.github.com/typpo/a2cfdc95a927b975505e8f3330f0efba